# Why isn't JOptionPane showing up?

Tags: java, swing, command-line

I made a simple JOptionPane class that should pop up with a string, when I type:

> `javac Hellodialog.java`

nothing happens at all. No error messages but nothing comes up.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Hellodialog
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "fsdfsdfdsfds");
    }
}
```

Comment: `javac` just compiles your code. Have you tried running it?

Answer (score 5):

## compile into a java `.class` file

> javac Hellodialog.java

## run the java class

> java Hellodialog

Answer (score 1):

You use the `javac` command to compile your source to byte code, and the `java` command to run your compiled code.